# How do I switch the if and if else when switching the text between buttons in android studio?

Tags: android

I am trying to switch the text between buttons like a puzzle game using the grid layout. I tried using an if statement but I feel I am doing it wrong. can any one give suggestions? Here is my java code

```
package com.example.kellito13.test;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        final Button btnOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
        final Button btnTwo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
        final Button btnFive=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFive);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(v == btnOne){
                    Button btn = (Button) v;
                    btn.setText("B");
                    btnOne.setText("A");

                }
                else if (v == btnFive){
                        btn.setText("E");
                        btnFive.setText("A");
                }
               /* Button btn = (Button) v;
                btn.setText("B");
                btnOne.setText("A");*/



            }

        });

        btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Button btnOne = (Button) v;
                btn.setText("A");
                btnOne.setText("B");



            }

        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch(id){
            case R.id.btnOne:
                btn.setText("B");
                btnOne.setText("A");
                break;
            case R.id.btnFive:
                btn.setText("E");
                btnFive.setText("A");
                break;
            default :

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.kellito13.test;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity Implement View.OnclickListener  {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        final Button btnOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
        final Button btnTwo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
        final Button btnFive=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFive);
        //In oncreate method register the listener for all button
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFive.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
//the following will be your original code....



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            switch(id){
                case R.id.btn:
                    //do stuff
                    break;
                case R.id.btnOne:
                    //do stuff
                    break;
                case R.id.btnTwo:
                    //do stuff
                    break;
                case R.id.btnFive:
                    //do stuff
                    break;
                default :
                    //do stuff
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This looks more easier than what I had. If I may ask , what I do about the if statement. It seems nothing happens when I add one. I want to able allow the user to either select the available button next to it.